# What's the best fingering for this passage? Single large shift or several small

Tags: violin, fingering

as part of my efforts to learn to play faster passages, I wrote the one posted below. However, I am having a lot of trouble figuring out the best way to finger it.

If I do a single, large shift I can play most of the notes clearly and with good intonation, but the note before the shift tends to get cut off when I am playing at speed.

However, if I do many small shifts all the notes tend do be less defined, and the chance of bad intonation is higher.

I recognize that in either case I will need to spend more time practicing in order to make it sound the way I want, but I hope that a more experienced violinist can help me figure out which version is worth practicing.

These are my ideas for fingering:

[image: Music excerpt]

Thanks!

Comment: here's another idea: 3 4314 3232 1431 4321 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first fingering looks pretty good to me.  The second one looks a bit awkward towards the end of the passage (between the G and A).  You could also try this: using the second fingering, at the A, use 1,2,1,2 (going to the G with your 2nd finger).  See what you think.